# Can I remove new line encoding from RS256 public key to store on .env files to be used on browser with frontend javascript app?

Tags: javascript, sha256

Can I remove new line encoding from below RS256 public key file? I have diff keys for diff env and want to keep this file on .ENV file  and will be used on browser with JavaScript module. Please suggest recommended way to store key file for JavaScript based web application.

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAnzyis1ZjfNB0bBgKFMSv
vkTtwlvBsaJq7S5wA+kzeVOVpVWwkWdVha4s38XM/pa/yr47av7+z3VTmvDRyAHc
aT92whREFpLv9cj5lTeJSibyr/Mrm/YtjCZVWgaOYIhwrXwKLqPr/11inWsAkfIy
tvHWTxZYEcXLgAXFuUuaS3uF9gEiNQwzGTU1v0FqkqTBr4B8nW3HCN47XUu0t8Y0
e+lf4s4OxQawWD79J9/5d3Ry0vbV3Am1FtGJiJvOwRsIfVChDpYStTcHTCMqtvWb
V6L11BWkpzGXSW4Hv43qa+GSYOD2QU68Mb59oSk2OB+BtOLpJofmbGEGgvmwyCI9
MwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: i'm using jwt.io with RS256 alg to generate hash and public private keys.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to include all relevant information. In this case, it would be nice to see what you've tried.

Comment: This question (and answer) may help: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19043/can-i-remove-newlines-in-a-public-key